# Inbox icon is red when I read all the messages

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found someone ask : http://answers.ros.org/question/700/answerrosorg-askbot-inbox-icon-is-red-when-inbox

But I also met this kind of problem.

It made me confused if I have new message or not.

Who can solve it? Or what can I do?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10800/inbox-icon-is-red-when-i-read-all-the-messages/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to wait for us to upgrade the server to the newer version with this patch.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-04**:
When will it about to work normal?